# aws emr pricing programmatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr

I have one requirement in which I am launching emr cluster pragmatically through Java api. Now I want to predict how much charge aws will take before launching emr cluster? I went through new aws pricing api but this api is not providing any information regarding charges applied on emr cluster? also I checked aws price calculator its totally based on javascript, so could you please suggest me any way through which  I can programmatically find the charges taken by aws emr pricing api?

Comment: Can you add a link where you find amazon emr pricing api 
I need to get the offercode for emr api

Comment: Hi Anoop,I checked a lot regarding amazon emr pricing api and also discussed with AWS support team but unfortunately there is no API for emr pricing we have to calculate EC2 price of node + EMR price of node to get price of AWS EMR instance...

Comment: Yes,AWS said that pricing is only available for core aws services only.